# How to recall a method specified no. of times when exception occurs

Tags: java, methods, execute

I tried to re-execute a method specified number of times when exception occurs in a method,
but I am unable re-execute the method

```
    int maxretries=10;
    void show(){
         try{
        display();
       }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     for(int i=1;i<maxretries;i++){
        display();//on first retry only I am getting exception
    }
    }
    }
```

when I run the code it is executed for first retry and I am getting exception but I want to reexecute `display()` method upto it is excuted successfully with in maximum retries.

Comment: Have you considered investigating why the exception is thrown and fixing the underlying issue instead of brute-forcingly calling a bugged code and hoping for the best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call you coded inside the catch is not inside a try, so it will not catch exceptions.

You need to use other concepts to do this, either calling the whole function again, or coding a successive try block inside the catch (and a further try block inside that catch block, etc.), or coding the loop around the whole try block (probably the best approach).

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
int maxretries = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < maxretries; i++) {
    try {
        display();
        break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In below program I am executing rerun method specified number of times even though exception occured with 5 sec time gap.

```
public class ReExecuteMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int count = 0;
        while (count <= 10) {
            try {
                rerun();
                break;
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                System.out.println(count);
                count++;
            } 

        }
        System.out.println("Out of the while");
    }

    static void rerun() {
//      throw new NullPointerException();
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```